# Duvida com Python+django

Tags: python, django

Estou iniciando com Python e  Django, seguindo um tutorial que encontrei:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Quando executo o comando `django-admin` com o startproject, ele não gera aquela estrutura de pasta que mostra no tutorial, apenas cria um arquivo que abre direto no `visualstudio.
Minha duvida é a seguinte, a estrutura é gerada automática, ou precisa ser criado na mão, se for automático, o que será que fiz de errado.

Estou utilizando `python 3.5` e `django 1.9.7`

Comment: Wellington, por favor coloque qual o arquivo que foi gerado, como nome e extensão.

Comment: assim que estiver em casa eu coloco ele aqui.. Muito obrigado por enquanto Rubico

Answer (score 2):

Wellington, boa tarde.

Também estou iniciando em Python e se não estou enganado, quando você está em ambiente Windows, os comandos no prompt de comando não devem usar o ".py" no final.

Apenas em ambiente Linux ou MAC que você usa o ".py" no final.

Vou fazer uns testes quando estiver com meu ambiente pronto em casa para confirmar.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal dando uma pesquisada melhor na documentação do django, eu acredito que descobri minha falha, eu estava rodando o comando `django-admin.py usando o .py no final do comando, sendo que nesse [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin), fala que pra usar sem o .py no final do comando. Fazendo meus testes e agora criou a hierarquia de pastas que eu estava esperando.

Comment: então feche a pergunta.